# How to populate autocomplete textview based on the selection of first?

Tags: android, android-volley, autocompletetextview

There are 2 autocomplete textview one for the city and one for the state. I want that when a user enters the state in autocomplete textview then based on state selection, city autocomplete text view should be automatically filled. Like the ecommerce app whenever someone enters the postal code in the address section then the city and state get automatically filled and also the user has the option to select.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edtxt_name_address, edtxt_email_address, edtxt_mobile_address, edtxt_alt_mob_address, edtxt_pincode, edtxt_addline1, edtxt_addline2;
    Button buttonSaveAddress;
    AutoCompleteTextView edtxt_city, edtxt_state;

    private static final String KEY_STATE = "state";
    private static final String KEY_CITIES = "cities";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String cities_url = "http://api.androiddeft.com/cities/cities_array.json";

    final List<State> statesList = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<String> states = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edtxt_city = findViewById(R.id.edtxt_city);
        edtxt_state = findViewById(R.id.edtxt_state);

        loadStateCityDetails();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, states);
        edtxt_state.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
        edtxt_state.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
        //edtxt_city.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)

        edtxt_state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        buttonSaveAddress = findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveAddress);
        buttonSaveAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveAddress();
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadStateCityDetails() {

        JsonArrayRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, cities_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray responseArray) {

                        try {
                            //Parse the JSON response array by iterating over it
                            for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject response = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String state = response.getString(KEY_STATE);
                                JSONArray cities = response.getJSONArray(KEY_CITIES);
                                List<String> citiesList = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < cities.length(); j++) {
                                    citiesList.add(cities.getString(j));
                                }
                                statesList.add(new State(state, citiesList));
                                states.add(state);
                                Log.d("lskd", String.valueOf(statesList));
                                Log.d("lskd", String.valueOf(states));

                            }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //pDialog.dismiss();

                        //Display error message whenever an error occurs
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

        // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);
    }

    private void saveAddress() {


        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(city)) {
            edtxt_city.setError("Please enter your City");
            edtxt_city.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(state)) {
            edtxt_state.setError("Please enter your State");
            edtxt_state.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        Intent profile_next = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileNextActivity.class);
        startActivity(profile_next);
    }
}
```

**State.java**

```
public class State {
    private String stateName;
    private List<String> cities;

    public State(String stateName, List<String> cities) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }

    public List<String> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

State and city has one to many relation, I didn't particularly understand what you meant by automatically filled. If you want to populate the related cities of the selected state do the following.

Inside your `edtxt_state.setOnItemSelectedListener`

```
edtxt_state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                statesList.get(position).getCities(); //get your cities from selected state
                //set adapter or notify city list of your `edtxt_city` AutoCompleteTextView
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't see any implementation of 'edtxt_city' in your code

Comment: ihave tried using like this but its not working ...ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, cityList);
                edtxt_city.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
                edtxt_city.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
edtxt_state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                List<String> cityList = statesList.get(position).getCities();
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, cityList);
                edtxt_city.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
                edtxt_city.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

set your adapter inside `loadStateCityDetails();` after getting `stateList`

```
statesList.add(new State(state, citiesList));
states.add(state);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, states);
        edtxt_state.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
        edtxt_state.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**EDIT**

```
edtxt_state.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                int pos = -1;

                for (int i = 0; i < statesList.size(); i++) {
                    if (statesList.get(i).getStateName().equals(selection)) {
                        pos = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }


                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, statesList.get(pos).getCities());
                edtxt_city.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
                edtxt_city.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
            }
        });
```

you must get `stateList`

set city adapter as above

Comment: statelist size=0 ...i think that why it is not showing in adapter

Comment: yes, you have to set adapter after getting api call response

Comment: after setting adapter like you told state values are not showing...but if i set the adapter in oncreate as i have done previously they are showing

Comment: set adapter in `onCreate()` and notify it after getting response, by using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: make sure your api returning list or you are not getting any `JSONException`